# Type ahead search in Ubuntu 18.04 file manager

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

In Ubuntu 16.04 file manager, when I type a few letters, it automatically selects the first file matching that sequence of typed letters inside the current directory. I think this is called `type ahead search`.

In Ubuntu 18.04, it instead opens a search and lists all the files that match, also recursively inside contained directories.

Is there a way to recover the old, Ubuntu 16.04 way of simply highlighting the first file that matches inside the current directory?